# can't boot into my dualboot win 7 and 8 systes

Tags: partitioning

My system has win 7 and win 8 ( Dual boot).
I don't see the boot menu to select the OS, it is stuck after POST and asking for boot media.
 I have resized the primary partition C:/ with win 7 using 'minitool partition wizard').
 After the resize process, I could not boot into my system. What to do? Please help.

Comment: my system has win 7 and win 8 ( Dual boot). I don't even see the boot menu for selecting OS. It is stuck after POST and asking for boot media.

Answer (score 0):

Can you still see the hard disk as the first boot device in BIOS?

Also,if you can boot from a USB/DVD, try the following:

1.Boot using Windows media and then select "repair your computer" and go to a command prompt
2.Use diskpart to verify that the disks and volumes are actually still present and recognized (or open notepad.exe and see if you can manually navigate to the drives). If you can't see the drives, then it's most likely a hardware issue and you need to run hardware diagnostics.
3.If you can see the disks,then run disk check using chkdsk /r
4.Try Using bootrec /fixmbr to fix the MBR partition table and bootrec/fixboot to fix the boot sector
5.Run a startup repair on the machine
6.Also use bootrec/scanos - More info on bootrec can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392
7.Run bcdedit and check the "Windows Boot Loader" values and where they point to

Comment: Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and edit you answer to make it readable.